# Problema ao criar vários usuários diferentes no django rest framework

Tags: python, django, login, token, django-rest-framework

Estou com um problema ao criar mais de um usuário e logar no django rest framework, estou usando um gerênciador de usuários personalizado para a criação de dois tipos de usuarios, pesquisadores e ofertantes, mas quando crio os meus usuarios e tento logar apenas consigo retornar um objeto de pesquisadores apesar de os dois tipos de usuários estarem criados no banco quando uso um comando **GET**   para verificar
*models.py*

```
class Users(models.Model):
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('active'), default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    username = models.CharField(_("Username"), max_length=50)
    cpf = models.CharField(_("CPF"), max_length=11)
    phone = models.CharField(_("Phone"), max_length=11, unique=True)
    siape = models.IntegerField(_("Siape"))
    email = models.EmailField(_("Email address"), max_length=254, unique=True)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Bidder(Users, AbstractBaseUser):
    type = models.CharField(_("type"), max_length=50)
    position = models.CharField(_("Position"), max_length=50)
    prorectory = models.CharField(_("Prorectory"), max_length=50)

    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    @property
    def token(self):
        token = jwt.encode(
            {
                'username': self.username,
                'email': self.email,
                'exp': datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=24),
            },
            settings.SECRET_KEY,
            algorithm='HS256'
        )
        return token
    objects = BidderManager()

    # For checking permissions. to keep it simple all admin have ALL permissons
    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    # Does this user have permission to view this app? (ALWAYS YES FOR SIMPLICITY)
    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True


class Researcher(Users, AbstractBaseUser):
    curriculum_lattes = models.URLField(
        _("curriculum"), max_length=255, unique=True)
    resume = models.TextField(_("Resume"), blank=True, default='')

    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    @property
    def token(self):
        token = jwt.encode(
            {
                'username': self.username,
                'email': self.email,
                'exp': datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=24),
            },
            settings.SECRET_KEY,
            algorithm='HS256'
        )
        return token
    objects = ResearcherManager()
```

*my_manager.py*

```
class ResearcherManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(
        self, username, email, cpf, curriculum_lattes,
        phone, siape, resume, password=None,
    ):
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('The given username must be set')

        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')

        GlobalUserModel = apps.get_model(
            self.model._meta.app_label, self.model._meta.object_name)
        username = GlobalUserModel.normalize_username(username)

        campus = users.models.Campus.objects.latest('id')
        academic_background = users.models.AcademicBackground.objects.latest(
            'id')

        researcher = self.model(
            username=username,
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            cpf=cpf,
            curriculum_lattes=curriculum_lattes,
            resume=resume,
            phone=phone,
            siape=siape
        )
        researcher.password = make_password(password)
        researcher.save(using=self._db)
        return researcher


class BidderManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(
        self, username, email, cpf, phone, siape, type,
        prorectory, password=None
    ):
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('The given username must be set')

        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')

        GlobalUserModel = apps.get_model(
            self.model._meta.app_label, self.model._meta.object_name)
        username = GlobalUserModel.normalize_username(username)

        
        bidder = self.model(
            username=username,
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            cpf=cpf,
            phone=phone,
            siape=siape,
            type=type,
            prorectory=prorectory
        )
        bidder.password = make_password(password)
        bidder.save(using=self._db)
        return bidder
```

Answer (score 0):

Só para salvar caso alguém sofra com o mesmo problema de authenticação de multiplos usuários, quando estava chamando o metodo authenticate ele funcionava apenas para uma tabela usuários, depois de longos estresses e analize encontrei o problema na authenticação do backend, que verificava apenas em uma modelo independente qual eu passasse na view.

**Solução**

Criei um novo backend e determinei manualmente a qual tabela ele deveria analizar, assim declarei meus backends em settings.py e deu tudo certo.